# Label an arrow with tikz-cd

Tags: tikz-cd

I would like to include a pentagon symbol with the letter "S" inside the Leftrightarrow between the two mappings in line 1 and 2 - means as a description in tikzcd.

[image]

I have included

```
\documentclass [a4paper,german,twoside,openright,11pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\hyphenation{Mathe-matik wieder-gewinnen}
%----------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx} % Einbindung von Grafiken (pdf, png, jpg)
\usepackage{float}            % bietet Option [H] für bombenfestes Verankern
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}   % Silbentrennung nach der neuen deutschen Rechtschreibung, z.B.: Sys-tem
\usepackage{amstext}          % für Klartext via \text{} in Formeln
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{csquotes}         % für komplexere Formeln (Mengensymbole ...)
\usepackage{amssymb}          % für komplexere Formeln (Mengensymbole ...)
\usepackage{pifont}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pifont
\usepackage{bm}               % bold math, für \bm{}
\usepackage{enumerate}        % verbessert Aufzählungen
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc} % Fussnoten am Seitenende
\usepackage{array}            % für Tabellen: bindet tabular-Umgebung ein
\usepackage{algorithm}        % für Algorithmen
\usepackage{algorithmic}      % für Algorithmen
\usepackage{pdfpages}         % für die Einbindung kompletter pdf-*Seiten*
\usepackage[right]{eurosym}   % Eurosymbol          % farbiger Text
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}     % für \url{http://www}, Option hyp erlaubt auch Umbruch nach "-"
\usepackage{makeidx}          % Package zur Indexerstellung
\usepackage{multicol}         % zur Indexerstellung in zwei Spalten
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-icomp, mergedate=basic]{biblatex}  \ExecuteBibliographyOptions{firstinits=true,maxnames=2}

\setlength{\bibitemsep}{10pt}
\setlength{\bibhang}{1.2cm}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}

\AtBeginBibliography{%
  \renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}%
  \renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}%
}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{%
  andothers = {et\addspace al\adddotspace},%
  andmore = {et\addspace al\adddotspace},%
}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpretobibmacro{author}{\mkbibbold\bgroup}{}{}
\xapptobibmacro{author}{\egroup}{}{}
\xpretobibmacro{bbx:editor}{\mkbibbold\bgroup}{}{}
\xapptobibmacro{bbx:editor}{\egroup}{}{}

\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\mkbibbold{\addcolon\space}}

\addbibresource{Dissertation.bib}  
\usepackage{nomencl}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{bussproofs}
\usepackage{stackrel}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage[linktocpage ]{hyperref}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt} % Headerlinie setzen
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt} % Footerlinie setzen
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RO]{\scshape \nouppercase \rightmark}
\fancyhead[LE]{\scshape \nouppercase \leftmark}
\fancyfoot[RO,LE]{\thepage} 

\usetikzlibrary{cd, shapes.geometric}

\newcommand*\pent[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
            \node[shape=regular polygon,draw,inner sep=1pt] (char) {#1};}}

\setlength{\epigraphwidth}{.8\textwidth}
\newcommand{\cmark}{\ding{51}}%
\newcommand{\xmark}{\ding{53}}%

\renewcommand{\indexname}{Personen- und Sachverzeichnis}
```

The code is

```
\begin{tikzcd}
X \arrow{r}[name=A, description]{\pi} & X/_{\sim}  \\
V \arrow{r}[name=B, description]{\pi} & V/_{\sim} \arrow[Leftrightarrow,to path=(A) -- (B)]{}
\end{tikzcd}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As  [egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg) noted, the problem seems to be how to draw the "S" inside a pentagon. Another solution, that is easily generalizable to other shapes is with tikz library `shapes.geometric` as in the following example

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{cd, shapes.geometric}

\newcommand*\pent[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
            \node[shape=regular polygon,draw,inner sep=1pt] (char) {#1};}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
X \arrow{r}[name=A, description]{\pi} & X/_{\sim}  \\
V \arrow{r}[name=B, description]{\pi} & V/_{\sim} 
\arrow[Leftrightarrow,from=A,to=B,"\pent{S}"description]
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9):

Similar to [Luis Turcio's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/581299/234180) but avoiding to nest `tikzpicture`s. You can just pass a list of options, such as the shape and so on, to the edge label.

```
\arrow[Leftrightarrow,from=A,to=B,
    "S"{description,regular polygon,draw=white,double=black,double distance=0.4pt,inner sep=1pt}]
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{cd, shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
X \arrow{r}[name=A, description]{\pi} & X/_{\sim}  \\
V \arrow{r}[name=B, description]{\pi} & V/_{\sim} 
\arrow[Leftrightarrow,from=A,to=B,
    "S"{description,regular polygon,draw=white,double=black,double distance=0.4pt,inner sep=1pt}]
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

The only problem seems to draw the pentagon with the inscribed letter.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{wasysym}

\newcommand{\Penta}[1]{%
  \mbox{%
    \vphantom{\large\pentagon}%
    \ooalign{%
      \large\pentagon\cr
      \hidewidth\raisebox{0.3ex}{$\scriptscriptstyle #1$}\hidewidth\cr}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}
X\arrow[r, "\pi" description, ""{name=top, below}] & X/{\sim}\\
V\arrow[r, "\pi" description, ""{name=bottom, above}] & V/{\sim}\\
\arrow[Leftrightarrow, from=top, to=bottom, "\Penta{S}" description]
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Code for the vertical arrow taken from the now deleted answer by Sandy G